# Is there any notification facility in OpenShift Origin?

Tags: openshift-origin

Our developers would like to get notifications whenever builds or deployments fail in their OpenShift projects (we are running OpenShift Origin 1.1.2). I could not find any mention of such functionality -- neither in the docs, nor in code nor in issues or the Trello board.

Is there something I've missed? Where is the notification functionality hidden in OpenShift?

Comment: Does not exist today, but you could potentially script it by watching all events generated by the cluster (oc get -w events --all-namespaces), filtering down to ones that you want to send, and sending emails.  Not everything is an event, but many of them are.  Opening an RFE on the GitHub issues with the things you want to notify will help us identify what we could add.